# android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x2 ArrayList

Tags: java, android, arraylist

When I try to test my app, I get an error.

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process: com.example.android.lab5, PID: 12261
>   android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x2

## Here's my code

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {    
    private Spinner spinnerVille;
    private TextView ville;
    private ListView lstJours;
    int posVille = 0;    

    // Les items
    private ArrayList<Jour> mJours = new ArrayList<Jour>();

    // L'adapteur
    private JourAdapteur mJoursAdapteur;

    private List<MeteoJour> meteojours;

    public static final int REQUEST_TEXT = 0;
    public int laPosition = 0;
    /**
     * ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
     * See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
     */
    private GoogleApiClient client;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(this);    

        Log.d("Insert: ", "Inserting ..");
        /*db.addMeteoJours(new MeteoJour(1, 2, 5, -2, 10, "SO", 8, 15, 1, 0));
        db.addMeteoJours(new MeteoJour(2, -1, 3, -4, 5, "NO", 8, 30, 0, 2));
        db.addMeteoJours(new MeteoJour(3, 2, 6, 1, 2, "SO", 8, 20, 2, 0));
        db.addMeteoJours(new MeteoJour(4, 3, 6, 3, 10, "SE", 8, 0, 0, 0));
        db.addMeteoJours(new MeteoJour(5, 4, 5, 4, 350, "S", 8, 30, 4, 0));
        db.addMeteoJours(new MeteoJour(6, 4, 7, 5, 0, "O", 8, 0, 0, 0));
        db.addMeteoJours(new MeteoJour(7, 6, 8, 8, 10, "E", 9, 15, 1, 0));
        db.addMeteoJours(new MeteoJour(8, 4, 5, 4, 350, "S", 8, 30, 4, 0));;
        db.addMeteoJours(new MeteoJour(9, 2, 5, -2, 10, "SO", 8, 15, 1, 0));
        db.addMeteoJours(new MeteoJour(10, 2, 5, -2, 10, "SO", 8, 15, 1, 0));
        db.addMeteoJours(new MeteoJour(11, 2, 5, -2, 10, "SO", 8, 15, 1, 0));
        db.addMeteoJours(new MeteoJour(12, 6, 8, 8, 10, "E", 9, 15, 1, 0));
        db.addMeteoJours(new MeteoJour(13, 2, 5, -2, 10, "SO", 8, 15, 1, 0));
        db.addMeteoJours(new MeteoJour(14, 6, 8, 8, 10, "E", 9, 15, 1, 0));
        db.addMeteoJours(new MeteoJour(15, 4, 5, 4, 350, "S", 8, 30, 4, 0));
        db.addMeteoJours(new MeteoJour(16, 2, 5, -2, 10, "SO", 8, 15, 1, 0));
        db.addMeteoJours(new MeteoJour(17, 2, 5, -2, 10, "SO", 8, 15, 1, 0));
        db.addMeteoJours(new MeteoJour(18, 4, 5, 4, 350, "S", 8, 30, 4, 0));
        db.addMeteoJours(new MeteoJour(19, 6, 8, 8, 10, "E", 9, 15, 1, 0));
        db.addMeteoJours(new MeteoJour(20, 2, 5, -2, 10, "SO", 9, 15, 1, 0));
        db.addMeteoJours(new MeteoJour(21, -1, 3, -4, 5, "NO", 9, 30, 0, 2));
        db.addMeteoJours(new MeteoJour(22, 2, 5, 2, 10, "SO", 8, 15, 1, 0));
        db.addMeteoJours(new MeteoJour(23, 2, 5, 2, 10, "SO", 8, 15, 1, 0));
        db.addMeteoJours(new MeteoJour(24, 2, 5, 2, 10, "SO", 8, 15, 1, 0));
        db.addMeteoJours(new MeteoJour(25, 2, 5, 2, 10, "SO", 8, 15, 1, 0));
        db.addMeteoJours(new MeteoJour(26, 6, 8, 8, 10, "E", 9, 15, 1, 0));
        db.addMeteoJours(new MeteoJour(27, 2, 5, 2, 10, "SO", 8, 15, 1, 0));
        db.addMeteoJours(new MeteoJour(28, 2, 5, 2, 10, "SO", 8, 15, 1, 0));
        db.addMeteoJours(new MeteoJour(29, 2, 6, 1, 2, "SO", 9, 20, 2, 0));
        db.addMeteoJours(new MeteoJour(30, 3, 6, 3, 10, "SE", 9, 0, 0, 0));
        db.addMeteoJours(new MeteoJour(31, 2, 5, -2, 10, "SO", 8, 15, 1, 0));
        db.addMeteoJours(new MeteoJour(32, 7, 10, 10, 10, "SO", 8, 15, 1, 0));
        db.addMeteoJours(new MeteoJour(33, 2, 5, 2, 10, "SO", 8, 15, 1, 0));
        db.addMeteoJours(new MeteoJour(34, 6, 8, 8, 10, "E", 9, 15, 1, 0));
        db.addMeteoJours(new MeteoJour(35, 2, 5, 2, 10, "SO", 8, 15, 1, 0));*/
        // Reading all contacts
        Log.d("Reading: ", "Reading all meteojours..");
        //final List<Contact> contacts = db.getAllContacts();
        meteojours = db.getAllMeteoJours();

        for (MeteoJour cn : meteojours) {
            mJours.add(new Jour((String.valueOf(cn.get_id()) + " Mars 2016"), cn.get_minimum(), cn.get_maximum()));
            String log = "Id: " + cn.get_id() + " ,Minimum: " + cn.get_minimum() + " ,Maximum: " + cn.get_maximum();
            // Writing to log
            Log.d("Name: ", log);
        }    

        spinnerVille = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerVille);
        ville = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Ville);
        lstJours = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lstJours);    

        // Adapteur
        //mHerosAdapteur = new HeroAdapteur(this, MonSingleton.getInstance().getHeros());
        mJoursAdapteur = new JourAdapteur(this, mJours);

        // Assigner l'adapteur à la liste
        lstJours.setAdapter(mJoursAdapteur);    

        // Create an ArrayAdapter using the string array and a default spinner layout
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
                R.array.villes, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        // Specify the layout to use when the list of choices appears
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinnerVille.setAdapter(adapter);

        spinnerVille.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapter, View v, int position, long id) {

                switch (position) {
                    case 0:
                        ville.setText("Gatineau");
                        posVille = 0;
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        ville.setText("Trois-Rivière");
                        posVille = 1;
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        ville.setText("Montréal");
                        posVille = 2;
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        ville.setText("Sherbrooke");
                        posVille = 3;
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        ville.setText("Alma");
                        posVille = 4;
                        break;
                }    
            }

            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
                // Another interface callback
            }    
        });

        //lstJours.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        lstJours.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                // La seconde activité
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Meteo.class);
                // Les paramètres

                meteojours = db.getAllMeteoJours();

                laPosition = position;

                MeteoJour cn = meteojours.get(position);
                // Les paramètres
                intent.putExtra("Id", String.valueOf(cn.get_id()));
                intent.putExtra("Min", cn.get_minimum());
                intent.putExtra("Max", cn.get_maximum());
                intent.putExtra("Ressentie", cn.get_ressentie());
                intent.putExtra("VitesseVent", cn.get_vent_vitesse());
                intent.putExtra("VetesseDirec", cn.get_vent_direction());
                intent.putExtra("Ensoleillement", cn.get_ensoleillement());
                intent.putExtra("Prob", cn.get_probabilite());
                intent.putExtra("Pluie", cn.get_pluie());
                intent.putExtra("Neige", cn.get_neige());
                intent.putExtra("villeslct", spinnerVille.getItemAtPosition(posVille).toString());
                intent.putExtra("joursslct", lstJours.getItemAtPosition(position).toString());
                startActivity(intent);
                // Lancer la seconde activité


            }
        });    

        // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
        // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
        client = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this).addApi(AppIndex.API).build();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        if (requestCode == REQUEST_TEXT) {
            if (resultCode == Meteo.RETURN_CODE_OK) {
                //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, data.getStringExtra("prenom"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                mJours.add(new Jour(data.getStringExtra("date"), data.getIntExtra("minimum", 0), data.getIntExtra("maximum", 0)));
                mJoursAdapteur.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }    
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
        // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
        client.connect();
        Action viewAction = Action.newAction(
                Action.TYPE_VIEW, // TODO: choose an action type.
                "Main Page", // TODO: Define a title for the content shown.
                // TODO: If you have web page content that matches this app activity's content,
                // make sure this auto-generated web page URL is correct.
                // Otherwise, set the URL to null.
                Uri.parse("http://host/path"),
                // TODO: Make sure this auto-generated app deep link URI is correct.
                Uri.parse("android-app://com.example.android.lab5/http/host/path")
        );
        AppIndex.AppIndexApi.start(client, viewAction);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();

        // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
        // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
        Action viewAction = Action.newAction(
                Action.TYPE_VIEW, // TODO: choose an action type.
                "Main Page", // TODO: Define a title for the content shown.
                // TODO: If you have web page content that matches this app activity's content,
                // make sure this auto-generated web page URL is correct.
                // Otherwise, set the URL to null.
                Uri.parse("http://host/path"),
                // TODO: Make sure this auto-generated app deep link URI is correct.
                Uri.parse("android-app://com.example.android.lab5/http/host/path")
        );
        AppIndex.AppIndexApi.end(client, viewAction);
        client.disconnect();
    }
}
```

I isolated my error and it seems to come from that line:

```
mJours.add(new Jour((String.valueOf(cn.get_id()) + " Mars 2016"), cn.get_minimum(), cn.get_maximum()));
```

The code of my java class `Jour` is :

```
 public class Jour {    
    private int mTempMin;
    private int mTempMax;
    private String mDates;

    public Jour(String date, int min, int max) {
        mTempMin = min;
        mTempMax = max;
        mDates = date;
    }    

    public String getmDates() {
        return mDates;
    }

    public void setmDates(String mDates) {
        this.mDates = mDates;
    }

    public int getmTempMin() {
        return mTempMin;
    }

    public void setmTempMin(int mTempMin) {
        this.mTempMin = mTempMin;
    }

    public int getmTempMax() {
        return mTempMax;
    }

    public void setmTempMax(int mTempMax) {
        this.mTempMax = mTempMax;
    }    
}
```

Thank you,
I hope we can find an answer!

*EDIT

Here's the MeteoJour class:

```
public class MeteoJour {

    //private variables
    int _id;
    int _minimum;
    int _maximum;
    int _ressentie;
    int _vent_vitesse;
    String _vent_direction;
    int _ensoleillement;
    int _probabilite;
    int _pluie;
    int _neige;


    // Empty constructor
    public MeteoJour(){

    }
    // constructor
    public MeteoJour(int id, int minimum, int maximum, int ressentie, int vent_vitesse, String vent_direction, int ensoleillement, int probabilite, int pluie, int neige){
        this._id = id;
        this._minimum = minimum;
        this._maximum = maximum;
        this._ressentie = ressentie;
        this._vent_vitesse = vent_vitesse;
        this._vent_direction = vent_direction;
        this._ensoleillement = ensoleillement;
        this._probabilite = probabilite;
        this._pluie = pluie;
        this._neige = neige;
    }

    // constructor
    public MeteoJour(int minimum, int maximum, int ressentie, int vent_vitesse, String vent_direction, int ensoleillement, int probabilite, int pluie, int neige){
        this._minimum = minimum;
        this._maximum = maximum;
        this._ressentie = ressentie;
        this._vent_vitesse = vent_vitesse;
        this._vent_direction = vent_direction;
        this._ensoleillement = ensoleillement;
        this._probabilite = probabilite;
        this._pluie = pluie;
        this._neige = neige;
    }


    public int get_id() {
        return _id;
    }

    public void set_id(int _id) {
        this._id = _id;
    }

    public int get_minimum() {
        return _minimum;
    }

    public void set_minimum(int _minimum) {
        this._minimum = _minimum;
    }

    public int get_maximum() {
        return _maximum;
    }

    public void set_maximum(int _maximum) {
        this._maximum = _maximum;
    }

    public int get_ressentie() {
        return _ressentie;
    }

    public void set_ressentie(int _ressentie) {
        this._ressentie = _ressentie;
    }

    public int get_vent_vitesse() {
        return _vent_vitesse;
    }

    public void set_vent_vitesse(int _vent_vitesse) {
        this._vent_vitesse = _vent_vitesse;
    }

    public String get_vent_direction() {
        return _vent_direction;
    }

    public void set_vent_direction(String _vent_direction) {
        this._vent_direction = _vent_direction;
    }

    public int get_ensoleillement() {
        return _ensoleillement;
    }

    public void set_ensoleillement(int _ensoleillement) {
        this._ensoleillement = _ensoleillement;
    }

    public int get_probabilite() {
        return _probabilite;
    }

    public void set_probabilite(int _probabilite) {
        this._probabilite = _probabilite;
    }

    public int get_pluie() {
        return _pluie;
    }

    public void set_pluie(int _pluie) {
        this._pluie = _pluie;
    }

    public int get_neige() {
        return _neige;
    }

    public void set_neige(int _neige) {
        this._neige = _neige;
    }
}
```

Here is the R.array.ville XML:

```
<string name="app_name">Lab5</string>

<string-array name="joursSemaine">
    <item>Dimanche le 28 février 2016</item>
    <item>Lundi le 29 février 2016</item>
    <item>Mardi le 1 mars 2016</item>
    <item>Mercredi le 2 mars 2016</item>
    <item>Jeudi le 3 mars 2016</item>
    <item>Vendredi le 4 mars 2016</item>
    <item>Samedi le 5 mars 2016</item>
</string-array>

<string-array name="villes">
    <item>Gatineau</item>
    <item>Trois-Rivière</item>
    <item>Montreal</item>
    <item>Sherbrooke</item>
    <item>Alma</item>
</string-array>
```

My log :

04-27 08:21:24.986 2342-2342/? I/art: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni 04-27 08:21:25.038 2342-2342/? D/Insert:: Inserting .. 04-27 08:21:25.210 2342-2342/? D/Reading:: Reading all meteojours.. 04-27 08:21:25.211 2342-2342/? D/Name:: Id: 1 ,Minimum: 2 ,Maximum: 5 04-27 08:21:25.211 2342-2342/? D/Name:: Id: 2 ,Minimum: -1 ,Maximum: 3 04-27 08:21:25.211 2342-2342/? D/Name:: Id: 3 ,Minimum: 2 ,Maximum: 6 04-27 08:21:25.211 2342-2342/? D/Name:: Id: 4 ,Minimum: 3 ,Maximum: 6 04-27 08:21:25.211 2342-2342/? D/Name:: Id: 5 ,Minimum: 4 ,Maximum: 5 04-27 08:21:25.211 2342-2342/? D/Name:: Id: 6 ,Minimum: 4 ,Maximum: 7 04-27 08:21:25.211 2342-2342/? D/Name:: Id: 7 ,Minimum: 6 ,Maximum: 8 04-27 08:21:25.211 2342-2342/? D/Name:: Id: 8 ,Minimum: 4 ,Maximum: 5 04-27 08:21:25.211 2342-2342/? D/Name:: Id: 9 ,Minimum: 2 ,Maximum: 5 04-27 08:21:25.211 2342-2342/? D/Name:: Id: 10 ,Minimum: 2 ,Maximum: 5 04-27 08:21:25.211 2342-2342/? D/Name:: Id: 11 ,Minimum: 2 ,Maximum: 5 04-27 08:21:25.211 2342-2342/? D/Name:: Id: 12 ,Minimum: 6 ,Maximum: 8 04-27 08:21:25.211 2342-2342/? D/Name:: Id: 13 ,Minimum: 2 ,Maximum: 5 04-27 08:21:25.211 2342-2342/? D/Name:: Id: 14 ,Minimum: 6 ,Maximum: 8 04-27 08:21:25.211 2342-2342/? D/Name:: Id: 15 ,Minimum: 4 ,Maximum: 5 04-27 08:21:25.211 2342-2342/? D/Name:: Id: 16 ,Minimum: 2 ,Maximum: 5 04-27 08:21:25.211 2342-2342/? D/Name:: Id: 17 ,Minimum: 2 ,Maximum: 5 04-27 08:21:25.211 2342-2342/? D/Name:: Id: 18 ,Minimum: 4 ,Maximum: 5 04-27 08:21:25.211 2342-2342/? D/Name:: Id: 19 ,Minimum: 6 ,Maximum: 8 04-27 08:21:25.211 2342-2342/? D/Name:: Id: 20 ,Minimum: 2 ,Maximum: 5 04-27 08:21:25.211 2342-2342/? D/Name:: Id: 21 ,Minimum: -1 ,Maximum: 3 04-27 08:21:25.211 2342-2342/? D/Name:: Id: 22 ,Minimum: 2 ,Maximum: 5 04-27 08:21:25.211 2342-2342/? D/Name:: Id: 23 ,Minimum: 2 ,Maximum: 5 04-27 08:21:25.211 2342-2342/? D/Name:: Id: 24 ,Minimum: 2 ,Maximum: 5 04-27 08:21:25.211 2342-2342/? D/Name:: Id: 25 ,Minimum: 2 ,Maximum: 5 04-27 08:21:25.211 2342-2342/? D/Name:: Id: 26 ,Minimum: 6 ,Maximum: 8 04-27 08:21:25.211 2342-2342/? D/Name:: Id: 27 ,Minimum: 2 ,Maximum: 5 04-27 08:21:25.211 2342-2342/? D/Name:: Id: 28 ,Minimum: 2 ,Maximum: 5 04-27 08:21:25.211 2342-2342/? D/Name:: Id: 29 ,Minimum: 2 ,Maximum: 6 04-27 08:21:25.211 2342-2342/? D/Name:: Id: 30 ,Minimum: 3 ,Maximum: 6 04-27 08:21:25.211 2342-2342/? D/Name:: Id: 31 ,Minimum: 2 ,Maximum: 5 04-27 08:21:25.211 2342-2342/? D/Name:: Id: 32 ,Minimum: 7 ,Maximum: 10 04-27 08:21:25.211 2342-2342/? D/Name:: Id: 33 ,Minimum: 2 ,Maximum: 5 04-27 08:21:25.211 2342-2342/? D/Name:: Id: 34 ,Minimum: 6 ,Maximum: 8 04-27 08:21:25.211 2342-2342/? D/Name:: Id: 35 ,Minimum: 2 ,Maximum: 5 04-27 08:21:25.218 2342-2360/? W/GooglePlayServicesUtil: Google Play services is missing. 04-27 08:21:25.254 2342-2361/? D/OpenGLRenderer: Use EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: true 04-27 08:21:25.259 2342-2342/? D/Atlas: Validating map... 04-27 08:21:25.271 2342-2342/? W/ResourceType: No package identifier when getting value for resource number 0x00000002 04-27 08:21:25.272 2342-2342/? D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM 04-27 08:21:25.291 2342-2342/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process: com.example.android.lab5, PID: 2342 android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x2 at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:299) at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:4132) at com.example.android.lab5.JourAdapteur.getView(JourAdapteur.java:41) at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2347) at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1270) at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1182) at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17547) at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChild(RelativeLayout.java:697) at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:481) at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17547) at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5535) at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:436) at android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:135) at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17547) at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5535) at android.support.v7.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onMeasure(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:391) at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17547) at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5535) at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:436) at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17547) at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5535) at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1436) at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:722) at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:613) at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17547) at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5535) at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:436) at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2615) at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17547) at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2015) at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1173) at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1379) at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1061) at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5885) at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:767) at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:580) at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:550)  at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:753) at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698) 04-27 08:21:28.734 2342-2342/com.example.android.lab5 I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 2342 SIG: 9

Comment: Can we see the `MeteoJour` class as well?

Comment: Can we also see how R.array.villes is set up in xml

Comment: @ChrisStillwell I've added the class

Comment: @kimchibooty I've added the string.xml file

Comment: I think the problem is `adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);` Your adapter is trying to read an integer resource (maybe of an integer position 2), and it can't, so that's the error. You should really add the entire logcat though so we don't have to guess

Comment: @cricket I've added the entire log

Comment: The error occurs on line 41, within `JourAdapteur.getView()` where you call `setText(2)`.